# How to return a json object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which returns me the following string:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko5u8752.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles"; 

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
   document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   console.log("Item is:" + document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML); 
  }
};


xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    //console.log("out is:" + out);
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
```

this returns me the following line correctly:

```
{"Item":{"title":"From student protest leader to Chile's president","id":"123456","data":"2021/12/20"}}
```

I want to return only the title using only this code. How can I do it?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) -> [Working with objects | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Why is the name of the variable `myArr`, and why does `myFunction()` expect an array if the response is clearly not an array?

Comment: Why do you ignore `myArr` and what `myFunction()` would do (when `arr` actually was an array) and overwrite the content of `#id01` with the unparsed `.responseText`?

Comment: excluding myfunction, the code works and returns the json above. myfunction i will modify it later to change my code. But if I want me back title what should I do?

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a If you want to grab a key/value pair from an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) just reference the `key` in the object to display its value. e.g. `console.log(someObj["Item"]["title"])`